# adminhtml config action location

Tags: magento-1.9, module, core

I am trying to learn about creating modules by looking at the core code to see how the directory structure is formatted. I was looking at the Magento 1.9 sales module.

In the adminhtml.xml file, The mage_sales module has children which each have their own action. These actions contain 'adminhtml/sales_order' or 'sales_invoice' for example. How is this method accessed? I thought because it depends on Mage_Sales, this means in the Mage/Sales directory and then the action implies the directory of where that method that's being called. So i assumed it would be in Mage/Sales/Block/adminhtml/'and be here'.

I just want to understand where these actions are located and how they are being called as I can't find them and I would like to know how Magento structures their modules so I have some guidelines to follow by looking at their code.

Answer (score 0):

Magento keeps all routes in the **controllers** folder under **app/code/[codePool]/[Package]/[Module]/etc/** directory.

Below is a sample:

http://example.com/catalog/product/view/id/2

**Base URL:** http://example.com/

**Module's front name:** catalog

**Controller class:** product

**Action name:** view

**Parameters and respective values:** id/2

You can have multiple parameters in the same pattern.

**Block** folder is meant for serving **functions** which are called by phtml files using `$this->functionName()`

To deep dive into Magento's module structure, you can start from [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-1.html).

Please let me know if you find any problem.